# How to view job details page for application sent in Careers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs

We can see the list of message sent for job application in careers portal. But we are not able to see the detail page of job we applied, because there is no links in message which will lead to job detail page.
We might not remember job details, if employer contacted back after a certain time. This can resolved by either of following two ways.

- Adding link of job detail page in message section for each application.
- Adding an new feature which will list recent all jobs applied with detail page link will helpful to view job description later.

Comment: Thing is, I don't think they archive the company pages. Once it's changed, there is no way to see past jobs. So link to the job page will soon become irrelevant as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, you are right. Then it will be irrelevant to greater extend. But it will good to implement at least in application with company pages that exist we need to forward to company pages, otherwise redirect to sorry page. This will be additional effort to devs, but it will be additional improvement in user experience.